# Find the latest string based on time and display those

Tags: powershell

I have a text file as shown below:

```
testdatabase-21-07-15-12-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-18-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-12-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-18-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-23-00
and many more like this (dynamically generated)
```

I am comparing (21/22-07-15) with another text file and if a match is found, I need to see which is the latest one. Like, if match is found for date 21-07-15, I need to retrieve the latest (which is 23) from the many of 21. Same as the case for 22,.... if match is found.

What I have done so far is:

```
$temp = Get-Content "C:\RDS\temp.txt"
foreach($te in $temp) 
{
  $t = $te -split '-'
  $da = $t[1]
  $mo = $t[2]
  $yea = $t[3]
  if("$da-$mo-$yea" -match $temp1)
  {
  # need to write the concept here
  }else
  {
   #nothing
  }
  }
```

How can I get this done.? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the lines read from the input file by a calculated property:

```
$fmt     = 'dd-MM-yy-HH-mm'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

Get-Content "C:\RDS\temp.txt" |
  sort { [DateTime]::ParseExact(($_ -split '-', 2)[1], $fmt, $culture) } |
  select -Last 1
```

Comment: Can I get the latest file of that particular date which is in for loop..?

Comment: @serverstackqns And that is supposed to tell me what exactly? What "latest file" for which "particular date" in what "for loop"?

Comment: These are not files. A single file with contents as shown above in the question.

Comment: @serverstackqns Please describe the problem in a complete and coherent manner, so that someone who does not sit in front of your computer is able to understand what you're talking about. Is something not working with the code I posted? If so: what were the results you expected, and how did that differ from the results you actually got?