# if loop not seems to be working

Tags: powershell

I have a code as given below:

```psh
$datearray = @()
$temp = Get-Content "C:\temp.txt"
$temp1 = Get-Content "C:\temp1.txt"
foreach ($te in $temp) {
  $t = $te -split '-'
  $da = $t[1]
  $mo = $t[2]
  $yea = $t[3]
  $fulldate = "$da-$mo-$yea"
  if ($temp1 -match $fulldate) {
    if ($fulldate -match $te) {
      $datearray += $_
      $fmt     = 'dd-MM-yy-HH-mm'
      $culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
      *!* $datearray | sort { [DateTime]::ParseExact(($_ -split '-', 2)[1], $fmt, $culture) } | select -Last 1 | Add-Content "c:\temp4.txt"
    } else {
      #some operation
    }
  } else {
    #some operation
  }
}
```

For your understanding, I will show you how `temp1.txt` looks like:

```
17-07-15
18-07-15
19-07-15
20-07-15
21-07-15
22-07-15
23-07-15
```

`temp.txt` is:

```
testdatabase-17-07-15-22-00
testdatabase-17-07-15-23-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-10-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00
```

What I am trying to do is that whenever it reaches the code marked with `*!*`, it goes back to `foreach` loop in the top every time. That marked code is not getting executed.

Can someone please tell me the solution?

Comment: Have you considered parsing the strings as actual datetime objects like in [your question yesterday?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582809/find-the-latest-string-based-on-time-and-display-those) - then you can do `$date.Year -eq 2015` instead of trying to match the string representation

Comment: Yes, whenever I execute that sort function, it goes to the foreach loop without getting executed that sort function. I want the entire 17-07-15 string to be matched, since I will be having so many dates within that text file.

Comment: Your code is a mess. `$temp1` contains an array, which can't be compared using the `-match` operator. `$fulldate` is a substring of `$te`, so `$fulldate -match $te` will always return `$false`. Also, `$datearray += $_` keeps adding `$null` to `$datearray`, because `$_` isn't populated at that point. What is your code supposed to achieve at the end of the day?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: At the end of the day, I need to retrieve the entry that is latest.
which means if I have 3 entries on date 17-07-15, then using "hh" need to check which is latest

Comment: The code in [my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31584897/1630171) should already do that by itself. No loops or ifs required.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: But I will have so many random generated lines as shown in the temp file example above. It may not be about just 2 or 3 dates, might have some 10 dates or so. And for taking each line by line, obviously I need for each loop. And whenever I am executing your code inside those for each, it is not getting executed completely. Whenever it reaches, Get-Content, it directly goes to the next for each loop.

Comment: So you want the most recent line for each date? Or just for specific dates?

Comment: yes, most recent line for each date and not for just specific dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) cmdlet to group the databases by date, then select the most recent database name from each group:

```psh
$fmt     = 'dd-MM-yy-HH-mm'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

Get-Content 'C:\temp.txt' |
  select @{n='Timestamp';e={[DateTime]::ParseExact(($_ -split '-', 2)[1], $fmt, $culture)}},
         @{n='Database';e={$_}} |
  group { $_.Timestamp.Date } |
  % { $_.Group | sort Timestamp | select -Last 1 -Expand Database }
```

The code uses a `select` statement to transform the list of lines into a list of custom objects with a `Timestamp` and a `Database` property in order to simplify grouping and sorting the database names by date.

Inspecting the output after each step of the pipeline should help you understand the logic behind this. `Get-Content` produces a list of strings with the lines from the file:

```
PS C:\> Get-Content 'C:\temp.txt'
testdatabase-17-07-15-22-00
testdatabase-17-07-15-23-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-10-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00
```

By using `Select-Object` with [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) the list of strings is transformed into a list of custom objects with 2 properties, the database name and the timestamp (as a `DateTime` object):

```
PS C:\> Get-Content 'C:\temp.txt' |
>> select @{n='Timestamp';e={[DateTime]::ParseExact(($_ -split '-', 2)[1], $fmt, $culture)}},
>>        @{n='Database';e={$_}}
>>

Timestamp                 Database
---------                 --------
17.07.2015 22:00:00       testdatabase-17-07-15-22-00
17.07.2015 23:00:00       testdatabase-17-07-15-23-00
21.07.2015 10:00:00       testdatabase-21-07-15-10-00
21.07.2015 23:00:00       testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00
```

Grouping these objects by the date portion of the timestamp gets you a list of `GroupInfo` objects whose `Group` property contains a list of the database names for a given date:

```
PS C:\> Get-Content 'C:\temp.txt' |
>> select @{n='Timestamp';e={[DateTime]::ParseExact(($_ -split '-', 2)[1], $fmt, $culture)}},
>>        @{n='Database';e={$_}} |
>> group { $_.Timestamp.Date }
>>

Count Name                Group
----- ----                -----
    2 17.07.2015 00:00:00 {@{Timestamp=17.07.2015 22:00:00; Database=testdatabase-17-07-15-22-00}, @{Timestamp...
    2 21.07.2015 00:00:00 {@{Timestamp=21.07.2015 10:00:00; Database=testdatabase-21-07-15-10-00}, @{Timestamp...
```

The `ForEach-Object` loop then sorts the elements of each group by timestamp and selects the last (most recent) database name from each group:

```
PS C:\> Get-Content 'C:\temp.txt' |
>> select @{n='Timestamp';e={[DateTime]::ParseExact(($_ -split '-', 2)[1], $fmt, $culture)}},
>>        @{n='Database';e={$_}} |
>> group { $_.Timestamp.Date } |
>> % { $_.Group | sort Timestamp | select -Last 1 -Expand Database }
>>
testdatabase-17-07-15-23-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00
```

Comment: This is actually the answer for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582809/find-the-latest-string-based-on-time-and-display-those/31584897#31584897

Since that is working with this code, this issue is also resolved. Thanks:)

Comment: @serverstackqns You would've gotten this answer earlier had you mentioned in your questions that you want the most recent name *per date*.

Comment: Anyway, thanks :) Can you please explain me the logic of what we've implemented (through chat if possible because I am having the same requirement this time, but within some 2 dates. Which means lets say in between 1 and 7, I need the most latest string, may be 06-mm-yy-22-30 or maybe 07-mm-yy-20, whatever be the latest.

Comment: @serverstackqns I updated my answer with some more explanation